# The output is not the supposed output for swapping element in same array

Tags: c#, arrays, element, swap

I created a sample list of numbers to store in the array and i want to swap the element in the same column.

```
1.(200,-400)
2.(300,-6000) 
3.(400,-125)
4.(100,-120)
```

The first group of number will swap with the second group of number making 1.(300,-6000) 2.(200,-400) 3.(400,-125) 4.(100,-120) then second group of numbers will swap with the third group of numbers becoming 1.(300,-6000) 2.(400,-125) 3.(200,-400), and this goes till the last array.

However I am not getting the output I am suppose to get... Can someone tell me whats wrong... Thank you.

```
private void swapButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] b1x = new double[4];
    double[] b1y = new double[4];
    double[] b2x = new double[4];
    double[] b2y = new double[4];
    double[,] array = new double[,]
    {
        {200,-400},
        {300,-6000},
        {400,-125},
        {100,-120}
    };

    for (int x =0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        b1x[x] = array[x, 0];
        b1y[x] = array[x, 1];

        for (int y = x+1; y < 4; y++)
        {
            b2x[x] = array[y, 0];
            b2y[x] = array[y, 1];
        }
        array[x, 0] = b2x[x];
        array[x, 1] = b2y[x];

        for (int w = x+1; w < 4; w++)
        {
            array[w, 0] = b1x[x];
            array[w, 1] = b1y[x];
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: What is your requirement? Where do you want to show output?

Comment: This is a so called test program. So when it works, I will bring it over to the main program. The output I displayed it in a MessageBox to check if it swapped correctly

Comment: Could you explain more about output? you are asking to swap a to b, b to c, c to d. In which variable you want to store?

Comment: take for example as above: first set is 200 and -400 and it swaps with the second set of 300,-6000. so the first set become 300, -6000 and second set becomes 200,-400. then the second set will swap with the third set and the second set becomes 400,-125 and the third set becomes 200,-400. Lastly the third set will swap with the last set and the third set becomes 100,-120 and last set becomes 200,-400

Comment: so the output will be like 1.300, -6000, 2.400,-125 3.100,-120 4.200,-400

Comment: Are you going to show 4 array's like array1={a,b,c,d}, array2={b,a,c,d}, array3={b,c,a,d}, array4={b,c,d,a}

Comment: yes something along those lines, except only showing the array4

Comment: Rachel Chia, could you use my answer to check your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start Array:

- {200,-400}
- {300,-6000}
- {400,-125}
- {100,-120}

End Array:

- {300,-6000}
- {400,-125}
- {100,-120}
- {200,-400}

To get this new array you can use the code below

```
private void swapButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] b1x = new double[4];
    double[] b1y = new double[4];
    double[] b2x = new double[4];
    double[] b2y = new double[4];
    double[,] array = new double[,]
    {
        {200,-400},
        {300,-6000},
        {400,-125},
        {100,-120}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var oldX = array[i, 0];
        var oldY = array[i, 1];

        var newX = array[i + 1, 0];
        var newY = array[i + 1, 1];

        array[i, 0] = newX;
        array[i, 1] = newY;

        array[i + 1, 0] = oldX;
        array[i + 1, 1] = oldY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, just a quick qns but it didn't work for me when i used i +1 for this part originally. May I know how comes it works here

Comment: The end condition of the for statement should be 3. First i wrote 4 just like you, but then the i+1 will be 4 and the array has only values for 0,1,2,3 but not 4. Maybe this is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have written this console application, may be this is what you are looking for. This prints the array in each of the steps with swapped value.

```
        double bx, by;

        double[,] array = new double[,]
        {
        {200,-400},
        {300,-6000},
        {400,-125},
        {100,-120}
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"({array[i, 0]}, {array[i, 1]})");
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {

            bx = array[x, 0];
            by = array[x, 1];

            array[x, 0] = array[x + 1, 0];
            array[x, 1] = array[x + 1, 1];

            array[x + 1, 0] = bx;
            array[x + 1, 1] = by;

            Console.WriteLine();

            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"({array[i, 0]}, {array[i, 1]})");
            }

        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score -1):

@Rachel Chia, I have redefined your code, kindly have a look. It may be helpful to you.

```
private void swapButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[,] array = new double[,]
           {
            {200,-400},
            {300,-6000},
            {400,-125},
            {100,-120}
           };
        double[,] b1 = array.Clone() as double[,];
        double[,] b2 = array.Clone() as double[,];
        double[,] b3 = array.Clone() as double[,];
        double[,] b4 = array.Clone() as double[,];

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            switch (x)
            {
                case 0:
                    b2[x + 1, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b2[x + 1, 1] = array[x, 1];

                    b3[x + 2, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b3[x + 2, 1] = array[x, 1];

                    b4[x + 3, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b4[x + 3, 1] = array[x, 1];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    b2[0, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b2[0, 1] = array[x, 1];

                    b3[0, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b3[0, 1] = array[x, 1];

                    b4[0, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b4[0, 1] = array[x, 1];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    b2[x, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b2[x, 1] = array[x, 1];

                    b3[x - 1, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b3[x - 1, 1] = array[x, 1];

                    b4[x - 1, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b4[x - 1, 1] = array[x, 1];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    b2[x, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b2[x, 1] = array[x, 1];

                    b3[x, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b3[x, 1] = array[x, 1];

                    b4[x - 1, 0] = array[x, 0];
                    b4[x - 1, 1] = array[x, 1];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but I would like to use loops instead of switch cases

Comment: Don't you want if condition instead of switch cases?

Comment: i want to use for loops

Comment: This answer made my day. You created a loop with all possible iteration conditions in switch. You know that if you get rid of loop you'll get exactly the same result?

Comment: @Zbigniew, i thought output should be in four array variables. So only i gave answer like this. I have asked the question about output. If he clearly explain about output like want to swap array[,] and show it into array[,] means i will give correct answer. Even i too don't want to do like this.